# Как настроить отображение валидации в angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть форма с вводом и кнопкой, необходимо настроить валидацию, чтобы при вводе с инпута и клике на кнопку строка отображалась выше. Прикрепляю код ниже:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'message-input',
    template: `<input [ngModel]="userName" />
    <button (click)="onNameChange(userName)">Отправить</button>`
})
export class MessageInput{ 

    @Input() userName:string;
    @Output() userNameChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
    onNameChange(model: string){

    this.userName = model;
    this.userNameChange.emit(model);
}
}

import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'message-list',
    template: `<div>Выбранное имя: {{name}}</div>
               <message-input [(userName)]="name" (userNameChange)="userNameChange($event)"></message-input>`
})
export class MessageList { 


userNameChange(name: string){
    name = "";
}
}
```

Comment: так а в чем проблема?

Comment: в том, что сообщения не отображаются, могу прикрепить скриншоты, если нужно

Comment: а что именно должно отобразиться? зачем вы используете двусторонную связку `[(userName)]="name"` вместе с генератором `(userNameChange)="..."`?

Comment: должна отобразиться строка, которая вводилась в поле инпут, отобразиться именно после клика кнопки

Comment: я просто учусь, возможно двусторонняя привязка не лучшая идея